# UWP Change keyboard language during runtime

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

Is there a way to change the language that Windows is using from a UWP app during runtime?

The app I am working on will be used in a kiosk environment and will be used by people with different languages. So the user needs to be able to change the language within the app, that will not only change the text displayed within the app, but also the input language on the Windows touch keyboard.

In WPF, you could simply change the CurrentInputLanguage property on the InputLanguageManager but there doesn't seem to be an alternative in UWP.

I know I can listen to the CoreTextServicesManager.InputLanguageChanged event when the input language is changed in Windows, but can't find anywhere to change it from the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For now, there's no build-in API for you to change the input language at runtime in UWP app. There's a [Language.TrySetInputMethodLanguageTag(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.language.trysetinputmethodlanguagetag#Windows_Globalization_Language_TrySetInputMethodLanguageTag_System_String_), but it only supports on IOT device. So, if the device has installed other languages, you could tell them to press <kbd>window</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> on screen keyboard to switch input language.

In addition, you could submit a "Feature Request" to [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: I have submitted a feature request on User Voice. Asking consumers to use Windows + space is not an option.